# SSH connection to GitHub from within Docker

Tags: git, docker, ssh

I'm going through some of the questions here to figure out how to connect to GitHub over SSH from within Docker, but I've had no luck.  My `docker build` requires an SSH connection.  Please help if you see what's wrong:

I have a private key at `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker` that I have added to GitHub. The key has no passphrase. This works from my shell:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker -vT git@github.com

...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker ED25519 SHA256:V...4 explicit agent
debug1: Server accepts key: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker ED25519 SHA256:V...4 explicit agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

This is my build command (from a Makefile recipe):

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1; docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker .
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM alpine

# Install ssh client and git
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Configure
RUN echo "Host *\n  AddKeysToAgent yes\n  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker" > ~/.ssh/config

# Connect
RUN ssh -vT git@github.com
```

The last line errors:

```
 > [5/6] RUN ssh -vT git@github.com:                                                                                                                                                                           
#10 0.234 OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022                                                                                                                                                            
#10 0.234 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#10 0.263 debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.3] port 22.
#10 0.298 debug1: Connection established.
#10 0.298 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
#10 0.298 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
#10 0.298 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
#10 0.299 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
#10 0.339 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-f33ee42f
#10 0.339 debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-f33ee42f
#10 0.339 debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
#10 0.339 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
#10 0.339 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
#10 0.339 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
#10 0.340 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
#10 0.341 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
#10 0.341 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
#10 0.341 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
#10 0.341 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
#10 0.341 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
#10 0.341 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
#10 0.387 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
#10 0.387 debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
#10 0.387 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
#10 0.387 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
#10 0.387 debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
#10 0.387 debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
#10 0.387 debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
#10 0.393 debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
#10 0.393 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
#10 0.393 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
#10 0.433 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
#10 0.433 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
#10 0.433 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
#10 0.433 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
#10 0.433 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
#10 0.473 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
#10 0.515 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
#10 0.515 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
#10 0.515 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
#10 0.515 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
#10 0.515 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The Docker Client API version is 1.41. What am I missing?  Going on hour 5 with this and going crazy :(

PS.  In case it's relevant: I've tried changing the RUN at the end of my Dockerfile to refer to the key by name:

```
RUN ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker -vT git@github.com
```

However this doesn't work; I see this new warning at the top of the log:

> #10 0.265 Warning: Identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker not accessible: No such file or directory.

Comment: and the key is passwordless, right?

Comment: and the key you want to use is one of those that say `trying private key....`?

Comment: "RUN ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker -vT..." vs " > [5/6] RUN ssh -vT..." The last line in your dockerfile doesn't match the command that you say is being run. Are you sure the dockerfile that you've included here is correct?

Comment: Can you run any `git` operations on the host, instead of in the Dockerfile?  There are a number of challenges with the approach you're describing here (getting credentials into the build without publishing them in the image, building alternate branches or uncommitted code, layer-caching considerations, ...) and it might be easier to avoid this setup entirely.

Comment: @eftshift0 that's right; the key has no passphrase

Comment: @eftshift0 the key is called `id_ed25519_docker[.pub]`, so it's not one of those shown in the "trying private key..." messages

Comment: "I have a private key at ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker that I have added to GitHub." Do you mean that you committed the private key and pushed it to your rep? Or that you added the public key in your user settings?

Comment: Also, when you use `~` in `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker` which user's home directory are you referring to? As you see in the output, the commands in your `Dockerfile` are run by the `root` user of the docker image.

Comment: @Kenster that's my mistake.  I've tried so many things.  I've updated the question to reflect that I'm currently trying `RUN ssh -vT git@github.com`.  I did try `RUN ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker -vT git@github.com` earlier and I get the warning: `#10 0.265 Warning: Identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_docker not accessible: No such file or directory. `.  Adding it to the Q in case it's relevant.

Comment: @BeetleJuice That's an error, not a warning. And the root cause of the problem: your private key isn't available inside the docker build.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok that's good news.  Not sure where to go from there; if I mistype the key name in the `docker build` (or use a key that's passphrase protected), the build errors right away, so I assume that my `docker build` is reading the key successfully since I see no such error.  Where to look from there?

Comment: @DavidMaze the git operation in Docker occur because the build needs to pull some private Github modules. But thank you; i'll think more deeply about whether this can be done outside and then the result copied into the image

Comment: @Code-Apprentice re: "Do you mean that you committed the private key and pushed it to your rep? Or that you added the public key in your user settings?"  I mean the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got things working with the following changes:

Changed my `docker build` command to remove any reference to the key name:

```
docker build --ssh default .
```

Changed my Dockerfile to:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine

# Install ssh client and git
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Connect
RUN --mount=type=ssh ssh -vT git@github.com
```

The key was to add `--mount-type=ssh` just before the execution that needed access to my host machine's ssh agent.  Without this, the execution cannot communicate with the host's ssh agent.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds